# How to add an entity without read back from the database using EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I would like to add or update an entity (with a `rowversion` column) in the database. Using SQL Server Profiler, I see the record is read after the update, to update the rowversion data in the dbcontext.

Since the `dbContext` goes out of scope, there is no need to read the inserted or updated record back. How can I prevent this read back?

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

var attachedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
attachedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();
```